# Updating z-index multiple times in order that menu item appears correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

There is a predictive search which creates a drop down menu of items the user can select from. Behind the dropdown there is a menu button which contains a z-index of 9999. Because of this the menu button appears in front of the dropdown menu. To fix this here is my solution :

Using jQuery listeners : 
Once the user clicks into the search box update the z-index of the button :

```
$( ".myIcon").css("z-index" , 1);
```

and once the user clicks off the search box using the 'blur' listener re-update the z-index :

```
$( ".myIcon").css("z-index" , 9999);
```

This works but it does not seem very clean. I do not have access to the code that is used to generate the drop down menu so cannot update the z-index of this item.

Is there another solution I am not aware of ?

Comment: can you post the `HTML` so we can see the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Give the parent of the search the same z-index**

Though it's hard to know what the html looks like since you didn't include an example. If you want it to appear on the same level then you can give it the same z-index from the gate. If the block the search part is in is after the nav, then they will naturally be on top of each other with the same z-index.

`#nav,#search{position:absolute;z-index:9999}`

for example, would put `#search` above `#nav` given that `#search` is after `#nav` in the html; like:

`<parent><nav/><search/></parent>`

If it is located before it, and possibly with a different parent, then you can use something like:

`#nav{z-index:9998} #search{z-index:9999}`

which would be if the html is more like:

`<search/><parent><nav/></parent>`

Though, if you need it to turn on/off the z-index, and it can't be fixed at all on `#search`, then you're already heading the right direction.

Something like this would be fairly easy:

```
$('#search input').on('focusin', function(){//on focus
    $(this).siblings('.myIcon').css({zIndex: '9999'});
}).on('focusout', function(){//on un-focus
    $(this).siblings('.myIcon').css({zIndex: '1'});
});
```

Though if you were able to control the css then you could just make a class for `.myIcon` with `z-index:9999` and instead use something like this:

`.on{z-index:9999}/*added css*/`

```
$('#search input').on('focusin focusout', function(){//on focus change
    $(this).siblings('.myIcon').toggleClass('on');
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/pxdz5/

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to request that the menu icon be changed to something a bit more reasonable?

There's no need to have it that high, simply 1 value above the next element is sufficient.

I'm sorry but I can't see any other way of solving this problem than the one you have suggested.

Comment: there is an item thats is z-index:9998 which needs to appear behind the menu item

Comment: You could request that this be lowered too, having the z-index up that high is seriously restrictive!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`$( ".myIcon").css("visibility" , "hidden");`

`$( ".myIcon").css("visibility" , "visible");`

Comment: I don't want to hide the element entirely